# Cannot update kernel on Ubuntu 16.04 "dpkg: error processing package"

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, update

I wanted to update the kernel of the Ubuntu VM I'm using on a cloud host which is stuck in 2.6 right now. I use Arch Linux on my desktop, so I'm used to my package manager giving me kernel updates every few days as part of updating regular packages, so I expected that running "apt-get upgrade" would take care of that. But when it finished, I was still on 2.6. I found [this page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_-_Xenial_Xerus) which recommends I install a few packages with the following command:

`sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04`

Now I get the following message when I try to install the package. I've tried googling for a solution and haven't found one.

```
root@server:~# sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-generic-hwe-16.04 is already the newest version (4.10.0.42.44).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y 
Setting up linux-image-4.10.0-42-generic (4.10.0-42.46~16.04.1) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-42-generic
vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-42-generic
) points to /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-42-generic
 (/boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-42-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.10.0-42-generic.postinst line 491.
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.10.0-42-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-42-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.10.0-42-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-42-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-42-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fixrtc failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-42-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.10.0-42-generic.postinst line 1052.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.10.0-42-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.10.0-42-generic:
 linux-image-extra-4.10.0-42-generic depends on linux-image-4.10.0-42-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.10.0-42-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.10.0-42-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04:
 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 depends on linux-image-4.10.0-42-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.10.0-42-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 depends on linux-image-extra-4.10.0-42-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-4.10.0-42-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-hwe-16.04:
 linux-generic-hwe-16.04 depends on linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 (= 4.10.0.42.44); however:
  Package linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic-hwe-16.04 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.10.0-42-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.10.0-42-generic
 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04
 linux-generic-hwe-16.04
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here's the output of a command I found in a thread about troubleshooting an issue that sounds similar to mine:

```
root@server:~# dpkg -l | grep linux-image*
iF  linux-image-4.10.0-42-generic       4.10.0-42.46~16.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.10.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-image-extra-4.10.0-42-generic 4.10.0-42.46~16.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.10.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04       4.10.0.42.44                          amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```